# How to implement individual options (like video and audio) of twilio in php

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am going to integrate twilio api in my project.

Here I want to give some options like listen only to audio instead of watching the video. How can I implement this option, i.e. how can I make the video to be invisible?

Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Comment: did you try to find out it in the twilio doc or twilio tutorial .
https://www.twilio.com/docs/ , 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials

Comment: I am not getting which one to use @Aabir Hussain

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When a participant joins a room the easiest way to show both their Video and Audio is to use [`attach()`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0-beta3/docs/Media.html#attach__anchor) to slot them into the DOM as a `<video>` element.

However, if you want independent control of the audio and video then you probably want to inspect and attach the participant's [`media.audioTracks` and `media.videoTracks`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0-beta3/docs/Media.html) separately. Each property is a map of a `Track.ID` and an [`AudioTrack`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0-beta3/docs/AudioTrack.html) or [`VideoTrack`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0-beta3/docs/VideoTrack.html). You can then `attach` and `detach` the individual tracks as you like over the course of the call.

Let me know if that helps at all.